# When does Express start reading the HTTP request body?

Tags: express, stream

When an HTTP request has a body, at what point does Express start reading from the request body?

Specifically, I've got an endpoint which looks like this (boilerplate omitted):

```js
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  const output = fs.createWriteStream('example.txt')
  req.pipe(output)
})
```

But I've noticed that sometimes there is data missing from the beginning of the output file; ie, it seems as though some data have already been read from the request's body before the handler is called.

So: at what point does Express start reading from the request body? And is there any way to block that until the handler gets called?

Answer (score 0):

Through experimentation, it appears that Node / Express starts reading the HTTP request body the first time `req.on('data', …)` is called.

To recreate the experiment, create a small Express app:

```js
const app = express()

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.on('data', d => console.log('data 1:', d))
  setTimeout(next, 100)
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.on('data', d => console.log('data 2:', d))
  next()
})

app.listen(8000)
```

And observe that, when a request with a body is sent, the only "data 1" will be logged:

```
$ curl -X POST -d 'hello, world' http://localhost:8000
data 1: <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21>
```

But if the first `req.on('data', …)` is removed:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // req.on('data', d => console.log('data 1:', d)) <-- this line is removed
  setTimeout(next, 100)
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.on('data', d => console.log('data 2:', d))
  next()
})
```

Then the "data 2" will be logged:

```js
$ curl -X POST -d 'hello, world' http://localhost:8000
data 2: <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21>
```

The important implication is here that care must be taken when writing middleware which reads from the body, as it could cause other middleware or handlers which read from the body to get incorrect data.

To avoid this, the request can be `paused()` (see [`Stream.pause`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause)) until all appropriate middleware has been attached:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.pause() // <-- called before any data are read
  req.on('data', d => console.log('data 1:', d))
  setTimeout(next, 100)
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.on('data', d => console.log('data 2:', d))
  req.resume() // <-- after all middleware has attached to the stream
  next()
})
```

*However*, this will break most existing middleware that expects it will be able to consume the entire request body (for example, `body-parser`, which provides `express.json()` and `express.form()`), so the stream must be `resume()`'d before they are applied.